# PHP: Can I add edit change logs to docx

Tags: php

I'm a Japanese.
So, my English is bad.... sorry.

---

### [QUESTION]

I want to write recording changes to .docx by php.
But I can't find any information.
In the first place, Can I write recording changes to .docx by php?

---

### [I WANT]

I want to write recording changes to .docx by php.
First, I have a .docx, it isn't empty.
I propose the .docx's text to users.
After the user rewrites the text, I want to write the changes .docx with editing histories like a revision.

I think, LibreOffice can do it...
But I Can't find any information.

Can I do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Ohaio, if you want to write a docx file with PHP, you may use PHPWord : https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord

Comment: Thank you for your advice!
Can PHPWord write editing histories like a revision?

Answer (score 0):

```
$docx = new \Phpdocx\Create\CreateDocx();
$docx->addText('This is a test');
$docx->embedHTML('New paragraph');
$docx->createDocx(WWW_ROOT . '/output.docx');
```

Answer (score -1):

https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord

it is available please tell what framework you are working

Comment: Whilst this could answer OP's question it is discouraged to provide link-only answers on StackOverflow as they can dissapear overtime

Comment: I have used CAKE PHP3.
Thank you

Comment: How  can I do? Thank you.